# ImageMagick: format supported on command line but not in C++ API?

Tags: image, format, delegates, imagemagick, decode

I am successfully using ImageMagick for a wide range of formats. However, I noticed that some of the (imo) more exotic formats work just fine when I call ImageMagick on them through the command line, but they fail when I try to load the same image using the Magick++ API.

For example, the AAI image formats:

On the command line everything works fine:

```
$ magick identify sample.aai 
sample.aai AAI 800x600 800x600+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.83106MiB 0.000u 0:00.002
$ magick convert sample.aai sample.jpg
$ magick identify sample.jpg 
sample.jpg JPEG 800x600 800x600+0+0 8-bit sRGB 109272B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Using Magick++ however, if I do:

```
Magick::Image image;
image.read("/the/path/to/sample.aai");
```

then it fails with the error:

```
Magick: No decode delegate for this image format (/the/path/to/sample.aai) reported by magick/constitute.c:1534 (ReadImage)
```

Anybody else encounter this issue before? Anybody any suggestions as to how to solve this?

Thanks,

Irigum

PS:

```
$ magick --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-48 Q16 x86_64 2020-12-10 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png raqm raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

My OS: Arch Linux 64-Bit

Comment: Please show all information returned from `magick -version` and also your platform/OS. Does magick++ convert a simple gif file?

Comment: I just added the full version info and my OS (Arch Linux 64 Bit). With magick++ I am able to load most image formats (including jpg, gif, etc.), I tested around 80 different formats successfully. Just a few of those that I would call more exotic formats simply fail to load in magick++ (but work on the command line).

Comment: You should report this to the ImageMagick GIT Bug reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagemagick API's rarely support all of Imagemagick's operators etc. It is down to the coder of the API to decide which ones are worth including.

Searching the web I found this page which allows you to see if your format is supported: https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/CoderInfo.html

```
CoderInfo info("GIF"); 
cout < info->name() << ": (" << info->description() << ") : "; 
cout << "Readable = "; 
if ( info->isReadable() ) 
  cout << "true"; 
else 
  cout << "false"; 
cout << ", "; 
cout << "Writable = "; 
if ( info->isWritable() ) 
  cout << "true"; 
else 
  cout << "false"; 
cout << ", "; 
cout << "Multiframe = "; 
if ( info->isMultiframe() ) 
  cout << "true"; 
else 
  cout << "false"; 
cout << endl;
```